# Hive: parse string into json

Tags: json, hive, user-defined-functions

I have a string column which is stored in json format

```
{"name":
    {"type":"json",
     "payload":"
         {\"id\": 
          \"123\",
          \"activities\": [....]  
         }
    }
 }
```

1. I need to parse it into json format.
2. and then turn it into map of <name, payload> where payload is rest of the json.
   "name" is a key and not a constant string.
   what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is presto's "JSON_PARSE" equivalent in hive?

Comment: your JSON is not valid one. payload value is not quoted properly.